# Dynamic Variable Scoping in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lisp, scope, tap

I'm interested in using dynamic (as opposed to lexical) scoped variables in Ruby.

It's seems there isn't a direct built-in way, as with `let` in Lisp.  One possible way to do dynamic scoped variable is suggested by [Christian Neukirchen](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2005/04/dynamic-variables-in-ruby.html).  He creates a "thread local hash" in his `Dynamic` class.  I wasn't too crazy about that.

Then I remembered that Ruby 1.9 has a `tap` method.  I see a lot of people using `tap` to print debugging values in a chain of commands.  I think it can be used to very nicely mimic a dynamically scoped variable.

Below is an an example of a situation in which one would want to use a dynamical scoped variable, and a solution using `tap`.

If I had a blog to post this on, and get some feedback, I would do it there.  Instead I come to S/O for criticism of this idea.  Post your critique, I'll give the correct answer to the one with the most upvotes.

---

### Situation

You have an ActiveRecord object representing an `Account`, each account `has_many` `Transaction`s.  A `Transaction` has two attributes:

- `description`
- `amount`

You want to find the sum of all `transactions` on the `account`, keeping in mind that `amount` can be either `nil` or a `Float` (no you can't critique that).

Your first idea is:

```
def account_value
  transactions.inject(0){|acum, t| acum += t.amount}
end
```

This bombs the first time you have a nil amount:

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

### Clean Solution

Use `tap` to temporarily define `amount = 0`.  We only want this to be temporary in case we forget to set it back and save the `transaction` with the 0 value still in place.

```
def account_value
  transactions.inject(0){|acm, t| t.amount.tap{|amount| amount ||=0; acm+=amount}; acm}
end
```

Since the assignment-to-zero-if-nil of `amount` is within the `tap` bock, we don't have to worry about forgetting to set it back to `nil`.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: "What are your thoughts?" Is that your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I think you're aiming for something else, but the following code fixes your example and is actually easier to understand:

```
transactions.inject(0) { |acum, t| acum += t.amount || 0 }
```

But I don't don't think the method summing up the amounts should know about the default value for `nil` amounts, so (even if your question states that I can't argue with it) I would change the `amount` method to return the default instead:

```
def amount
  @amount || 0
end
```

Nevertheless I think your example is just too easy to solve and you're actually aiming for answers to a more complex question. Looking forward to all the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see where the dynamic scope in your solution is. `tap` introduces a new lexically scoped block, the values are restored according to the lexical scope.

BTW, the `let` in Common Lisp doesn't create dynamically scoped variables by itself, either. You have to `declare` the variables `special` to make that happen (or it will redefine the value of a variable dynamically if that variable is already `special`).

EDIT: For the sake of completeness, I quickly implemented a class that implements actual dynamic variable behaviour: http://pastie.org/1700111

The output of that is:

```
foo
bar
foo
```

EDIT 2: Here's another implementation that does this for instance variables without the need for a wrapper class: http://pastie.org/1706102

Answer (score 2):

The problem stated can be solved by using the `||` operator (as shown by rubii).

You can further simplify this by calling the `sum` method on the Array.

```
account.transactions.all.sum {|t| t.amount|| 0 }
```

On the other hand, group calculations should not be done in Ruby. The DB should do all the heavy lifting.

```
account.transactions.sum(:amount) # SELECT SUM(amount)
                                  # FROM   transactions
                                  # WHERE  account_id = account.id
```